# TranslateModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9, angular-providers

I have migrated my angular application from version 5 to version 9. When I am trying to build it is throwing below error.

```
"TranslateModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type."
```

I have searched in stackoverflow for the same and found few solution but I am bit confused as my TranslateModule.forRoot is written is same app.module.ts. I am not sure what and how should i pass the argument to make it work as its defined only in app.module.ts file. Please is the structure which I am having in my app.module.ts file.

[image]

Comment: Which version of `@ngx-translate/core` are you using?

Comment: I am using @ngx-translate/core version 8

Comment: Can you try updating `@ngx-translate/core` to version 12? See the [compatibility table](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#installation)

Comment: sure, I will do it

Comment: will ng update @ngx-translate/core@12 will work to update it?

Comment: I don't think that the package supports `ng add`, but you can run `npm install --save @ngx-translate/core@12`

Comment: sure, will try the command which you mentioned

Comment: If I upgraded the translate and loader version it threw an error "Errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I upgraded angular from 15 to 16  where my **`@ngx-translate`** version was **11.0**.

After upgrading **`@ngx-translate 15.x`** my issue resloved.

**Command:**  npm install --save @ngx-translate/core@15 --force

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had the same problem, as Samuel said I updated ngx-translate. These are available versions compatible to angular versions.
In my case by Upgrading Angular 13 to 14, I had to update ngx-translate/core to 14 , and ngx-translate/http-loader to 7.
In my case, I could also updated them to the latest.
Above table shows Angular compatibilty with ngx-translate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!